# Showing monic arrows are iso

Tags: category-theory

If we have the following where $a,b,d$ are some objects in some category and the arrows are some monomorphisms (sorry for the lack of diagrams I am not sure how to do them without tikz)

$g:b\rightarrowtail d$ and $f:a\rightarrowtail d$ and  $i:a\rightarrowtail b$ and $j:b\rightarrowtail a$

such that $f=gi$ and $g=fj$ I am trying to show that $i,j$ are isomorphism and are the inverse of each other.

I am sure that this is relatively simple but I am just not getting it.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Are all of the above arrows intended to be monomorphisms?

Comment: This is indicated by the $\rightarrowtail$ (and the observation that otherwise the claim isn't true). One only needs that $f$, $g$ are monomorphisms (this already implies that $i,j$ are monomorphisms).

Comment: I have written this into the text, so people (like myself), do not have to read the small print. Hope that helps

Comment: @magma: Thanks! I'm familiar with the tail arrows convention, but I find it helpful to have it in writing just so I know we're on the same page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One doesn't need any ideas to write down the proof. Here is a general recipe:

1. What do we want to show?
2. What do the assumptions tell us?
3. Proof.

We want to show $ij=1$. By assumption ($g$ monic) it suffices to prove $gij=g$. By assumption ($f=gi$) this means $fj=g$. This is true by assumption.

The proof of $ji=1$ is analoguous.